# How to reopen closures with fewer than 5 votes?

Tags: support

The following both involved the participation of moderator KitFox, so would five reopen votes still be needed or simply the number that closed?

https://english.stackexchange.com/q/185219/50720 was closed by tchrist, Robusto, KitFox♦.

https://english.stackexchange.com/q/185214/50720: I've since emended this. I tried to flag this but was confused; two were marked as declined and one helpful.

Comment: Reopening is the same; 5 votes needed.

Comment: At the risk of confusing things still further, I've just cast the third and final ***delete*** vote against the first question linked to here. I don't know whether it would be automatically be ***reopened*** in the unlikely event that five hi-rep users voted to ***undelete***. Maybe there would have to be another five votes to complete the resuscitation process, but I'm not holding my breath. I see nothing of interest in the *much [of] the same* question, and I've no reason to disagree with it being unilaterally closed by a mod.

Comment: Regarding the (for-the-nonce-)remaining second question, no, it shouldn’t be reöpened either. That question is fully congruent to requesting a discursive treatise on what nuances may or may not apply to the variant phrasings *all of the foo* and *all the foo* and *all foo*. This is just needling nothingness that will produce no other better answer than “Nothing whatsoever beyond pointless verbosity for verbosity’s sake”.  It is not a reasonable question, and it would not generate reasonable answers. Please consider our sister-site for [ell.se] given your clear state as a perplexed learner.

Comment: All votes are equal. But some votes are more equal than others. And we want it that way.

Answer (score 4):

Closed questions need 5 votes to reopen, regardless of how many votes it took to close.

From the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions):

> Users with 3,000 reputation can cast up to 24 reopen votes per day. When a question reaches 5 reopen votes, it is no longer closed, and new answers may be submitted. You may only vote to close or reopen a question once. To cast a reopen vote, click the "reopen" link beneath the question.

There is also useful information [about closures](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) in the section about the close vote privilege.